# Async function return Observer object and Promise <Pending>

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise

I have function like below:

```
    async getData(): Promise<any[]> {
        const result = fetch(`someURL`);

        return result.map(async (e) => new DataModel(
            e.login, e.id, e.avatar, await this.getOrderAmount(e.login)
        ));

    }
```

```
const [ data ] = Promise.all([ this.getData() ])
```

why he return me someone like this:
[image]

thanks for any help

Comment: What is that  `fetch` function? The standard fetch api does not return an object that has a `map` method.

Comment: `const [ data ] = Promise.all([ this.getData() ])` seems pointless, you should write `const data = Promise.resolve(this.getData())` or even just `const data = this.getData()` to the same effect.